# "Show all results" only if more then 10 results

Tags: wordpress, search

In my livesearch, i am using the link "Show all results" at the bottom. is it possible the show the link ONLY if there are more then 10 Results?

This is the code i am using atm

```
$search_messages = array(
    'all_results_query'   => http_build_query($_REQUEST),
    'all_results_link'    => home_url('?' . http_build_query($_REQUEST)),
    'view_all_results'    => __('Show all results')
);

$output .= "<a class='vd_search_entry_view_all' href='".$search_messages['all_results_link']."'>".$search_messages['view_all_results']."</a>";
```

Comment: use count of all listing

Answer (score 0):

Got a working solution for me

```
global $wp_query;
if($wp_query->found_posts > 10) {
    $allezeigen = "<a class='vd_search_entry_view_all' href='".$search_messages['all_results_link']."'>".$search_messages['view_all_results']."</a>";
} else {
    $allezeigen = "";
}
echo $allezeigen;
```